# LuaRocks installing Alien

Tags: lua

I want to install library via LuaRocks to access functions from dlls. Unfortunately i didn't find binaries so i thought that i need to compile a ffi library on my computer. After a long while of googling i found Alien library so i wanted to install it via command `luarocks install alien`. Then I received a message:

```
Installing https://luarocks.org/alien-0.7.1-2.src.rock

Error: Could not find library file for FFI
  No file ffi.lib in c:/external/lib
  No file ffi.dll in c:/external/lib
  No file libffi.dll in c:/external/lib
You may have to install FFI in your system and/or pass FFI_DIR or FFI_LIBDIR to
the luarocks command.
Example: luarocks install alien FFI_DIR=/usr/local
```

And it didnt install library. I would know what i am doing wrong, and my question is how to install this library / get some ffi lib dll binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alien is binding to [libffi](https://github.com/libffi/libffi). And because LuaRocks does not deal with external
deps you have to build it byself and put it in e.g. `c:\external` dir.
Also Alien has few problems on Windows. I can suggest use my [rockspec/repo](https://github.com/moteus/alien/blob/master/rockspecs/alien-scm-0.rockspec)

I have basic distro with few external libraries [luaenv](https://github.com/moteus/lua-windows-environment). You can find there
prebuild libffi static library for Win32 compiled with MSVC 10/15. I fail build it for Win 64. Also libffi has problems with bulding as dll with MSVC. And I got 
access violation when try use versions > 3.1.

There also exists [luaffi](https://github.com/jmckaskill/luaffi) library that has no external deps and it should be easy compiled on Windows. New fork [luaffifb](https://github.com/facebook/luaffifb) provides rockspec file but it not released yet and I fail to build it with both MSVC 10/15.

And of course there exists LuaJIT which has builtin ffi module.